# Shuffling elements of an RDD[List[Double]] in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In a program I am developing using Spark 2.3 in Scala, I have an `RDD[List[Double]]`. Every `List[Double]` have the same size. I can't figure out how to perform a transformation that given the `RDD`

```
[1.0, 1.5, 4.0, 3.0],
[2.3, 5.6, 3.4, 9.0],
[4.5, 2.0, 1.0, 5.7]
```

transform it in the `RDD`

```
[2.3, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0],
[1.0, 5.6, 4.0, 5.7],
[4.5, 1.5, 3.4, 9.0]
```

where every single element of the lists is swapped among them, maintaining the same position.

For example, the first element of the first list is moved to the first position of the second list, the second element of the first list is moved to the second position of the third list, and so on.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now. I don't know if there's an easy way to do this. You essentially want to randomize each "Column" - but RDDs are row based.

Comment: Yep, you've got it! I am looking at Dataframes right not.

Comment: I think the only way is to split each "Column" into it's own RDD or DataFrame, then randomly sort each of them, and finally join them back together

Comment: The size of each list is small enough. I think your solution is approachable :) would you like to answer the question?

Comment: Either I don't understand what you want, or the title of the question is misleading. Do you want to "independently shuffle each column in an RDD" or something like this? Sampling an element from an `RDD` seems to be a quite different process...

Comment: You’re right. I meant shuffling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to shuffling column-wise would be to break down the dataset into individual single-column DataFrames each of which gets shuffled using `orderBy(rand)`, and then piece them back together.

To join the shuffled DataFrames, RDD `zipWithIndex` is applied to each of them to create row-identifying ids.  Note that `monotonically_increasing_id` won't cut it as it doesn't guarantee generating same list of ids necessary for the final `join`.  Hence, this is rather expensive due to the required transformation between RDD and DataFrame.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val rdd0 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    List(1.0, 1.5, 4.0, 3.0),
    List(2.3, 5.6, 3.4, 9.0),
    List(4.5, 2.0, 1.0, 5.7)
  ))
//rdd0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[Double]] = ...

val rdd = rdd0.map{ case x: Seq[Double] => (x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3)) }
val df = rdd.toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

val shuffledDFs = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("c")).map{ c =>
  val subDF = df.select(c)
  val subRDD = subDF.orderBy(rand).rdd.zipWithIndex.map{
    case (row: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ id)
  }
  spark.createDataFrame( subRDD,
    StructType(subDF.schema.fields :+ StructField("idx", LongType, false))
  )
}

shuffledDFs.reduce( _.join(_, Seq("idx")) ).
  show
// +---+---+---+---+---+                                                           
// |idx| c1| c2| c3| c4|
// +---+---+---+---+---+
// |  0|2.3|2.0|4.0|9.0|
// |  1|1.0|5.6|3.4|3.0|
// |  2|4.5|1.5|1.0|5.7|
// +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do `val df = rdd.toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")`, because `rdd` is trasformed by Spark in a single column Dataframe :( Any suggestion?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin, sorry I missed the `RDD[List[Double]]` bit.  Please see my updated answer, assuming each of the list elements isn't big (size <= 22).